# How can I find a record which has no matching value in a joined table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have these SQL Statements:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Phrase   -- Returns 660 rows

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Score    -- Returns 660 rows

SELECT count(*)               -- Returns 660 rows
FROM Score AS S
JOIN Phrase AS P ON S.PhraseId = P.PhraseId

SELECT count(*)               -- Returns 658 rows         
FROM Score AS S
JOIN Phrase AS P ON S.PhraseId = P.PhraseId
JOIN Category AS C ON P.CategoryId = C.Id
```

I am trying to work out what went wrong in the database and would appreciate some advice on how I could find the phraseId of the records where a phrase has a categoryId that's not in the table Category

Comment: As SQL lite doesn't support full outer join, you either have to emulate it using left joins and a union or use not exists/not in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an outer join:

Return all records from score and phrase that match.  Include rows from Category that match.  Then exclude all of those that had a match on category, leaving you the 2 records from score/phrase that didn't match a category.

```
SELECT *
FROM Score AS S
JOIN Phrase AS P ON S.PhraseId = P.PhraseId
LEFT JOIN Category AS C ON P.CategoryId = C.Id
WHERE C.ID is null
```

Not as efficient as not exists/not in but gives you more flexibility on the columns returned.

Answer (score 2):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to find such ids in the `Phrase` table.

```
  SELECT * FROM Phrase AS P 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Category WHERE P.CategoryId = C.Id)
```

Another solution is to use `NOT IN` however you have to be more careful about possible NULLs

```
  SELECT * FROM Phrase AS P 
  WHERE P.CategoryId NOT IN(SELECT C.Id FROM Category WHERE C.Id IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have 2 Phrase records with CategoryId = NULL, assuming there is a referential integrity constraint between Phrase and Category.

Anyway, this should list these 2 Phrase records:

```
SELECT * FROM Phrase WHERE CategoryId NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM Category)
```

Answer (score 1):

use can use nested subquery to get this

```
select count(*)
from score as S
where phraseId in 
(select phraseId
    from Phrase
    where phaseId not in (select phraseId from category);
```